# Error when building Android Room Database in class RoomOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am following this example [here](https://github.com/srinurp/RoomRxJava) and integrating it into my current app I am developing. I had previous sql databases but I am not trying to migrate them.

I have the libraries setup and all the code in but when i try to build to test on emulator i get this error.

```
Error:(27, 60) error: constructor RoomOpenHelper in class RoomOpenHelper cannot be applied to given types;
required: DatabaseConfiguration,Delegate,String,String
found: DatabaseConfiguration,<anonymous Delegate>,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

It seems the 'RoomOpenHelper' needs a identityHash and legacyHash. the legacy has is not provided and I cannot figure out why.

Here are the libraries I am using

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.0"

implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0-alpha1"

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.0"
```

I have tried with and without the common java8 library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by updating the 2 persistence libraries to a 1.1.0 alpha build

Answer (score 1):

It usually caused by variations in room dependencies. Make sure the normal dependency, the annotation dependency, and rxjava support dependency are all in the same version.